# What is the difference between SerializableCoder and AvroCoder?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, serializable

What is the difference between SerializableCoder and AvroCoder, and when should I use the one over the other on a customized data model? From the documentation page it seems that AvroCoder is more strict on the model schema, and SerializableCoder just need the model to implement Serializable interface which is essentially empty. The document for SerializableCoder did warn about not guaranteeing a deterministic encoding. Beside that, what would be a situation that one would choose AvroCoder over SerializableCoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that AvroCoder use [Avro Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.3.0/GettingStartedGuide/avroschemas.html), i.e., you would use AvroCoder for .avro files only.

An Avro schema is created using JSON format, like this:

```
{
"type" : "record",
"name" : "userInfo",
"namespace" : "my.example",
"fields" : [{"name" : "username", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"},

            {"name" : "age", 
            "type" : "int", 
            "default" : -1},

            {"name" : "phone", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"},

            {"name" : "housenum", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"},

            {"name" : "street", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"},

            {"name" : "city", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"},

            {"name" : "state_province", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"},

            {"name" : "country", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"},

            {"name" : "zip", 
            "type" : "string", 
            "default" : "NONE"}]
}
```

On the other hand, SerializableCoder implements the [Java Serializable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). This allows to have classes intended for object serialization, but there are no specific methods.

Additionally, avro schemas can be read by non-java applications.